# Open URL in browser from Message Button using Slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am sending the users a slack message with a button through a Slack App. On every click of the button, I generate a new URL.

At the moment, I am able to return the URL back as a message. The user clicks on the message to open the URL in the browser.

Instead of the sending a message back, I want to open the URL directly in the browser using slack API.

How can I accomplish it? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that does that.

Thanks

PS: Google Drive integration does that already.

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer by @mackwerk is now dated and incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately slack does not support opening urls from message buttons.
You can monitor what slack is planning on releasing here though: https://trello.com/b/ZnTQyumQ/slack-platform-roadmap-for-developers :)

Comment: This is what I got from the slack developers group as well. "It's unfortunately not possible to accomplish it -- the Google Docs integration is an odd duck with some unique capabilities."

Comment: Yep! Some things have special integrations, like spotify, soundcloud and youtube as well to name a few :)

Comment: This would be a fantastic feature. Add "url" to the actions block for messages. If the user clicks the button - open that URL.

Comment: This is no longer true, look for correct answer in other answers

Answer (score 53):

It appears Slack introduced this feature recently.

As documented in https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#button

```
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "button",
      "text": "Book flights ",
      "url": "https://flights.example.com/book/r123456"
    }
```

It's possible to preview in [Slack's interactive message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3C%40W1A2BC3DD%3E%20approved%20your%20travel%20request.%20Book%20any%20airline%20you%20like%20by%20continuing%20below.%22%2C%22channel%22%3A%22C061EG9SL%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Book%20your%20flights%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fflights.example.com%2Fbook%2Fr123456%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Book%20flights%20%F0%9F%9B%AB%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fflights.example.com%2Fbook%2Fr123456%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: Using URL appears to prevent it from triggering the "interactive_message_callback". Anybody else?

Comment: It seems that message attachments are now deprecated in favour of the new [block kit API](https://api.slack.com/block-kit). Does anyone know of a way to make buttons open a link, but with the block kit?

Comment: This answer is also depreciated. See @anabella answer for updated api

Answer (score 5):

According to Slack, message `attachments` is the "old way" of composing messages, which will be deprecated in favour of the new [Block Kit API](https://api.slack.com/block-kit).

I found [this example](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22This%20is%20a%20section%20block%20with%20a%20button.%22%7D%2C%22accessory%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Click%20Me%22%7D%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_123%22%2C%22action_id%22%3A%22button%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22actions%22%2C%22block_id%22%3A%22actionblock789%22%2C%22elements%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Primary%20Button%22%7D%2C%22style%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22click_me_456%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Link%20Button%22%7D%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fblock-kit%22%7D%5D%7D%5D) on how to do button links on their docs, using the `actions` object in the message payload.

I haven't implemented it yet, but you can send the message to a channel in your workspace straight from the docs and try it, and it does open the link in the browser as expected.

Comment: Seems that if you does not send an acknowledgment response for provided url, you will get a little exclamation mark in triangle near buttons. [Documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#button) says `If you're using url, you'll still receive an interaction payload and will need to send an acknowledgement response.`

Answer (score 2):

Update 04/2022

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "View",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "style": "primary",
                    "url": "https://flights.example.com/book/r123456"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Test on Slack Blockit Builder: [Link](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder)

[image]