# Open web page via Slack slash command

Tags: slack, slack-commands

[This question asks about opening a URL from a slack message button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404788/open-url-in-browser-from-message-button-using-slack-api), but I want to know, can you directly open a webpage with a [Slack slash command](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands)?

From those docs it seems like it's not possible at this point, but perhaps I missed something.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, slack do not have interaction with our computers.

But!!!! everything is possible right?

If you really want to do it, follow the guide below

1. create an application or script that listen to a specific endpoint like /openbrowser and, after a specific request, this script will open your browser
2. make this app reachable from the internet, with ngrok
3. create a slash command and point this command to your ngrok_address/openbrowser

It will work, but only in your computer. You cannot publish it